# Spammers on Drupal 6 site

Tags: users, advertising

I think Im getting some spammers adding user accounts to my site. I've been checking the users section of my site daily and I'll see these strange email addresses. So I check on the reports and find that they are spammers. Has anyone encountered this problem? Im currently researching it to try and stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Spambot module](http://drupal.org/project/spambot) is a great solution for protecting the registration form:

> Spambot protects the user registration form from spammers and spambots by verifying registration attempts against the Stop Forum Spam (www.stopforumspam.com) online database. It also adds some useful features to help deal with spam accounts.

I'd definitely recommend it

Comment: +1 for spambot, it does a great job preventing spammers from signing up on your site

Comment: @MotoTribe You should really take the credit for that one, I wouldn't even know about it if it wasn't for you ;)

Comment: Thanks, I tried Spambot and it seems to be working. I'll have to set it up on my live site later. I like that it allows me to check existing users. I checked ones I thought were spammers and I was right, they were definitely spammers.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this happens a lot on public sites.  I suggest looking into three solutions:

[Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) is a good CAPTCHA based form protector, but it is somewhat unique in that it doesn't always challenge users with the CAPTCHA.  It uses some logic to detect the spamminess, and then presents the CAPTCHA on an as-needed basis.  This may or may not work well on the user registration form (I am not sure if I have tried it here).  It works very well on comment and contact forms.

[reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) is a module for integrating with the service we all have been used to the last few years.

[Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) adds a hidden field to a form, and then double checks that the field is empty/unchanged upon submission.  Typically, spambots autofill these fields.  The end result is that the form protection is transparent to end-users, but does a good job of keeping out the bots.  I have had good luck with this approach on user registration forms.

Comment: I read somewhere that Mollom isnt free for sites that have higher traffic. I'll check on that because I don't think that will fly with my boss :( and we tend to have high traffic. I'm liking Honeypot though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.  Mollom charges for legitimate posts; you don't get charged for spam.  Every time we have used it, clients have fit into the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on [Captcha](http://drupal.org/project/captcha), it will prevent bots from registering on your site.
2. Enable Email verification, this will prevent users to enter valid
   email ids.
3. Use contrib modules like [spam bot](http://drupal.org/project/spambot), [login tobagan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) which will automatically
   delete users who have not verified their accounts within X no of
   days.

This will save you trouble of verifying accounts manually, once its automated.

Comment: I've been looking at/using spambot and it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the discussion on G.D.O., http://groups.drupal.org/node/77093.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Normally, link-only answers aren't considered good ones.  Can you summarize the link and mention how you think it will help this particular user's situation?

Comment: Or you can add this as a comment to the question, but this is too short to constitute an answer.